# how to add Thousand separator in pie chart tooltips of charts.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

i need to add thousand separator in pie chart tooltips, i had tried to add this

`multiTooltipTemplate : function(label){return label.datasetLabel + ': ' + label.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");}`

into my code and but it dosnt work.
this is my full code :

```
var pieChartCanvas = $('#pieChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
        var pieChart       = new Chart(pieChartCanvas)
        var PieData        = <?php echo json_encode($pasar2); ?>;
        var pieOptions     = {
          multiTooltipTemplate : function(label){return label.datasetLabel + ': ' + label.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".");},
          //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
          segmentShowStroke    : true,
          //String - The colour of each segment stroke
          segmentStrokeColor   : '#fff',
          //Number - The width of each segment stroke
          segmentStrokeWidth   : 2,
          //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
          percentageInnerCutout: 10, // This is 0 for Pie charts
          //Number - Amount of animation steps
          animationSteps       : 100,
          //String - Animation easing effect
          animationEasing      : 'easeOutBounce',
          //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
          animateRotate        : true,
          //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
          animateScale         : false,
          //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
          responsive           : true,
          // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
          maintainAspectRatio  : true,
          //String - A legend template
          legendTemplate       : '<ul class="<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>'
        }
        //Create pie or douhnut chart
        // You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
        pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function(label){
    //Assuming the label.value is a number
    let amount = label.value.toFixed(2);
    let tooltipLabel =  label.datasetLabel + ': ' + amount.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");

    return tooltipLabel; 
}
```